# Bidirectionnal communication Socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets

I am developing two scripts to send a file from a Client to a Server using Socket in Python. I can successfully send and receive the file from both Client Side and Server Side. 
Now, I would like the Server to send a confirmation that the whole file has been received (Send a simple string). But when, I try to receive from the Client side it seems to stop the program.

Here is my code to send the file and receive the status on the Client side :

```
zip_data_file = open(zip_file_name, 'rb')
data = zip_data_file.read()
while data:
    self.sock.send(data)
    data = zip_data_file.read()
print('File sent !')
zip_data_file.close()
state = str(self.sock.recv(1024).decode())
```

And here is the code for receiving/creating the file and send the status :

```
with open(new_file_name, 'wb') as file_created:
    data = connection.recv(1024)
    print('Receiving the file...')

    while data:
        file_created.write(data)
        data = connection.recv(1024)
print('Successfully got the file ', new_file_name)
connection.send("Done".encode())
```

Does anyone know where it could be from or how to solve this problem ?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> while data:
>     file_created.write(data)
>     data = connection.recv(1024)
> ```

You assume that `data` will somehow be empty if the client is done sending. But the only concept of "done" built into TCP is to shutdown the connection. Without such a shutdown the server will not be aware that the client is finished but will instead expect the client to send more data.

One way to trigger such shutdown is to `close` the socket. Only this will close the whole connection and the client will not be able to receive any data from the server. Instead you can do a one-side shutdown with `self.sock.shutdown(1)` in which case the client will signal that it will not send any more data in the TCP connection but will still be able to receive data from the server:

```
self.sock.shutdown(1)
state = str(self.sock.recv(1024).decode())
```